# Would there be an IoT use cases where sensor and actuation are at two different locations

Tags: sensors, actuators

I am thinking of application that if there is fire or machine failure at remote location, then some action (like an alarm or emergency light) is taken at a different location. (Like a control or response room).

In most cases, this is achieved by sending a notification on cell phone and let the user take the action. I am wondering if there are any IoT applications which instead acts on one location based on sensor data collected from another location (with or without notifications).

Reason I am asking is I am finding it difficult to connect two different physical addresses on cloud and I am wondering if this is usually done or not.

Comment: Classic example -> The Good Night Lamp http://goodnightlamp.com/

Comment: Please update the question with what exactly you are having problems with. having actions happen at multiple locations is a pretty standard thing for connected devices.

Comment: Thanks @hardillb. I will update it but for now as standard as the applications are, this answers my query. (I was not able to search it or probably was not using the right search terms).  I will try to do some own research on the specific issues I am facing and then post if I continue to have a problem.

Comment: absolutely; i have a light on my desk at work that blinks when someone rings my home doorbell...

Answer (score 0):

You can use a controller like Domoticz or Openhab or any other and use a gateway in between to make your sensor and actuators speak to each other. Mysensors.org is one way to go.

Comment: Hi Puneit, it would be great if you could elaborate a bit about the different solutions you mentioned and why and when one might pick one above the other.